# According to the Bible were bibleic Egyptians and Pharaos Iaphetan/Japhetan?

Tags: genesis, moses, abraham, genealogy, egypt

I have consulted the [Gen 10](https://biblehub.com/sepd/genesis/10.htm) but not sure how the actual people at each particular moment of time would map to that genealogy of Noah sons.

Of a particular interest would be to know the provenance of Egyptians and Pharaos at the time of Abraham and at the time of Moses.

Because Pharaos and Egyptians in general owned land, I would assume they were indeed Iaphetan/Japhetan as the firstborn of Noah inherited the land. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that the Hebrew word for "Egypt" is מִצְרַיִם (Mitsrayim - note the name of the official airline of egypt = "Air Mizraim"), one of the sons of Ham as per Gen 10:6

> The sons of Ham: Cush, Mizraim, Put, and Canaan.

In V13 we read -

> Mizraim was the father of the Ludites, the Anamites, the Lehabites,
> the Naphtuhites

The official and oddest name for Egypt is given from this sentence from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egypt

> "Miṣr" (Arabic pronunciation: [mesˤɾ]; "مِصر") is the Classical
> Quranic Arabic and modern official name of Egypt, while "Maṣr"
> (Egyptian Arabic pronunciation: [mɑsˤɾ]; مَصر) is the local
> pronunciation in Egyptian Arabic.[21] The name is of Semitic origin,
> directly cognate with other Semitic words for Egypt such as the Hebrew
> "מִצְרַיִם‎" ("Miṣráyim/Mitzráyim/Mizráim").

Thus, there is little doubt that Ham's son, Mizraim, according to Gen 10 settled in What is no Egypt (the Greek name for that place).

The word פַרְעֹה (pharoh) is simply the name of the kings of Egypt.  According to NAS Exhaustive concordance, the word is of foreign (to Hebrew) origin, ie, from the Egyptians themselves.  The meaning of the word is:

> great house, of royal court (BDB)

Comment: Thanks for an informative answer to the point. Now does bible have any explicit confirmation that Mizraim indeed were the people owning (and governing that may or may not be the same thing) the land of Egypt at the time of Abraham and separately Moses? It could be that between Noah and now quite a few migrations and power takeover took place.

Comment: Small typo "in What is no Egypt" should be "in what is now Egypt", I guess.

Comment: @grammaplow - the people of Egypt still call themselves "Mizr".

Comment: this is now... and AFAIK they have nothing to do with the ancient Egyptians.